# Trying to create grok pattern for my logs, but unsure how to escape special charaters

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

```
07:40:28,339 INFO  [org.sprinframework.web.context.ContxtLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 672)  WebApplicationContext: initialization started
```

I wrote the pattern like this

```
grok { 
      match => { "message" => "%{TIME:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{DATA:classname}%{SPACE}%{DATA:url}{THREADPOOL:thread}%{SPACE}%{DATA:logs}" }

}
```

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. More specifically, please include a question and what you tried and didn't work out (and why). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grok pattern you need is:

```
%{TIME:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}\[(?<logger>[^\]]+)\]%{SPACE}\((?<thread>[^)]+)\)%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```